# Changing listening ports with openSSH

Tags: networking, server, ssh

i recently decided to turn my old desktop pc into a linux server where i can host my files etc. I followed a tutorial which used openssh and after installing it and configuring some files it works like a charm. I have a few questions though: the tutorial i followed [here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-in-linux/) uses nc -v -z [addr] [port] to check if the ssh service is working on that port. However, no matter which port i use in the sshd_config file, it won't successfully listen on that port. Any ideas why?

PS: i'm a complete beginner to linux :)

*Running on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: Are you running the `nc` command with the loopback address `127.0.0.1` as shown in the guide you linked? from where are you running the command?

Comment: @steeldriver no,I'm using the local one and I'm running it from /home

Answer (score 1):

`sshd`, the `ssh` server, reads its config file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) on `sshd` startup.

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

is one way to make this happen.

Comment: No, it will not. It will cause it to no longer accept new sessions on the old port, but existing sessions will be allowed to proceed.

Comment: So should i try this or is it "dangerous"?

Comment: You should try it. What makes you think it's "dangerous"? You can see which port `sshd` is listening to by `sudo lsof -c sshd -a -i`